# Need some help on an MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am stuck on this query.

My problem is in the syntax. I can't seem to find the correct way to match records in the "LIKE" clause and to exclude the records that do not match the "LIKE" clause.

I am using a CASE statement because I need to format the output according to the LIKE conditions.

Sample of MYSQL code I am using is posted below.

I have also included an image showing how I desire the output to be formatted.

The image of the desired output is found below.

[MySQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW1EL.png)

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.SalesID, SS.Contact
CASE CONTACT
WHEN Contact IS LIKE '%Manuel%'
THEN WORKS
WHEN Contact IS NOT LIKE '%Manue%'
THEN NO
END AS Manuel?
FROM Salespeople S
LEFT JOIN Studios SS
ON (S.SalesID = SS.SalesID)
WHERE SS.Contact = 'Manuel Austin' Or
SS.Contact IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: voted to close as TYPO resolved in a manner unlikely to be useful to future readers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a lot of syntax problems in your query.

You can use this query:

```
SELECT S.SalesID,
CASE WHEN ss.Contact LIKE '%Manuel%' THEN 'WORKING WITH MANUEL'
ELSE 'NOT WORKING WITH MANUEL' END AS Manuel
FROM Salespeople S
LEFT JOIN Studios SS
ON (S.SalesID = SS.SalesID)
GROUP BY S.SalesID,
CASE WHEN ss.Contact LIKE '%Manuel%' THEN 'WORKING WITH MANUEL'
ELSE 'NOT WORKING WITH MANUEL' END
ORDER BY s.SalesID
```

You shouldn't check in the where clause anything about manuel or when the column are null, since you need all the results no matter if they have manuel as their contact.

So you just need to left join, and use case.

Comment: Why not? What does using the "?" do to the query?

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks. I am using mysql.

Comment: nope! Doesn't work. Still an error, but thanks.

Comment: It worked! But there is a minor issue.

Comment: It worked! But there is a minor issue. I need to remove duplicate entries. How can I remove the duplicate entries? For some reason, "DISTINCT" didn't remove duplicates.

Comment: You can wrap it with another select and put the distinct outside.. SELECT DISTINCT SALESID, Manuel FROM (THE QUERY HERE) @BIG_MAC_AND_FRIES

Comment: I didn't down vote you. I upvoted you! I was so desperate trying to solve this!!

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using a query within a query?

Comment: Yes I know, I dont know who downvoted me but you can upvote yet, you can only accept answer (pressing the V sign near the arrows) anyway, you can use group by. In 1 min the answer will be updated. @BIG_MAC_AND_FRIES

Comment: I figured it out. I use the GROUP BY to remove duplicates!